# How to add all dates in between two dates to array in powershell

Tags: date, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to add all the dates between 08/27/14 to 10/27/14 to an array in the yyyyMMdd format. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: have a look at the `new-timespan` cmdlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks guys, as always once I posted on the forum an idea pops into my head. This seems to work for what I need.

```
$startDate = Get-Date 08-27-14
$endDate = Get-Date 10-27-14
while($startDate -le $endDate){
$nextDate = Get-Date $startDate -format yyyyMMdd
write-host $nextDate
$startDate = $startDate.AddDays(1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$date = [datetime]'08/27/2014'

 $array = 
   do {
       $date.ToString('MM/dd/yy')
       $date = $date.AddDays(1)
      }

    until ($date -gt [datetime]'10/27/2014')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date -Year 2014 -Month 08 -Day 27) -End (Get-Date -Year 2014 -Month 10 -Day 27)
for ($i = 1; $i -le $ts.Days; $i++) {[array]$dates += ((Get-Date -Year 2014 -Month 08 -Day 27).AddDays($i))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this. I made a function out of this

```bsh
function New-DateArray {

    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [DateTime]$StartDate,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [DateTime]$EndDate
    )

    [Array]$DateArray = @()

    while ((Get-Date $StartDate.tostring('yyyy-MM-dd')) -lt (Get-Date $EndDate.tostring('yyyy-MM-dd'))){
        $NextDate = Get-Date $StartDate
        $DateArray += $NextDate
        $startDate = $startDate.AddDays(1)
    }

    $DateArray += $EndDate

    Return $DateArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = Get-Date '2014-08-27'
$end   = Get-Date '2014-10-27'

$dates = for ($date = $start; $date -le $end; $date = $date.AddDays(1)) {
    $date.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
}
```

Seems about as clean as you can get.